# Corona SDK - SQLLite Local Database and Updating

Tags: sqlite, coronasdk

I was just looking for some guidance with my app design. I'm going to have a local sqllite database pre populated with about 1000 records.

These records will need to be read frequently within the app to update the UI.

The records will need to be updated from within the app.

Is a local mysql database the best way to do this or should I be storing all this info in a massive lua table? The database has 2 tables one with 2 columns and one with 10 columns.

I don't want the data to be accessible from outside the app as some of the data is going to be paid for content.

How would I go about releasing updates in the future? If I upgrade my app to version 2 and add new records to the database... how would I go about keeping the users existing data in the database and just adding the updated stuff?

Hope someone can point me in the right direction!

Many Thanks,

Krivvenz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is fairly simple question. If you need to use data after closing and opening the app you will need sqlite. If the data is created and lost after the app usage, then a table will do. However, the sqlite has also the advantage of querying, deleting and so many other functions without loops etc that you may need to do in tables manually. 
You can also append further data during app update. The Sqlite file you create is saved to document directory. That is not deleted if you only update. Simply write a code in your update that reads the existing database and appends the new data. Or create a new file for sqlite and use the old one as backup.